# Showing the InkWell splash only on pressed widget when it's inside another InkWell widget

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a container widget which is wrapped inside `InkWell` widget for the tap sound, tooltip and splash effect purposes, inside it there's another `InkWell` widget for the same purposes but for a different `OnTap` action.

When i long press the outside container it shows the splash on everything (which is understandable, but when i press the internal widget it shows the splash on the outer widget as well, which gives the illusion it's the same widget.

The different `InkWell` widgets **DO** act like different widgets, the `OnTap` and `OnLongPress` act as they should, my problem is the splash animation.

[I included a GIF to explain it better](https://gph.is/2qKn5u3),
how can i prevent the splash on the outer container when user presses the internal one?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14417

> What's going on here is that both ink wells are fighting for the
>   pointer in the arena, and during the fight they show their reactions.
>   When one wins, the other will get canceled.
>
> We don't have an easy way today for the outer InkWell to know that
>   it's fighting with another InkWell for the same gesture.